# Can an Artificer with an All-Purpose Tool gain Eldritch Blast cantrip and take the feat Eldritch Adept to get Agonizing Blast Invocation

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, feats, cantrips

Can an Artificer with an All-Purpose Tool gain *Eldritch Blast* cantrip and take the feat Eldritch Adept to get Agonizing Blast Invocation?

> All-Purpose Tool: [...] As an action, you can focus on the tool to channel your creative forces. Choose a cantrip that you don't know from any class list. For 8 hours, you can cast that cantrip, and it counts as an artificer cantrip for you. Once this property is used, it can't be used again until the next dawn.

> Agonizing Blast - Prerequisite: *Eldritch Blast* cantrip - When you cast Eldritch Blast, add your Charisma modifier to the damage it deals on a hit.

If the Artificer chooses a different cantrip the following day, they still have the invocation right, it just doesn't function till the Artificer chooses *Eldritch Blast* the day after?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 29):

#### Eldritch Adept does not give access to invocations with prerequisites unless you are a warlock.

Eldritch Adept states:

> If the invocation has a prerequisite of any kind, you can choose that invocation *only if you’re a warlock* who meets the prerequisite.

Since Agonizing Blast has a a prerequisite, you cannot take it unless you are a warlock, even if you know or can cast *eldritch blast*.

Comment: So it would work (an intelligence-based Eldritch Blast with a charisma-based Agonizing Blast modifier to the damage) if the Artificer were able to dip a level of Warlock? Kind of niche and inefficient, but possible.

Answer (score 1):

#### Even if Eldritch Adept allowed it, you wouldn't fill the prerequisites.

The Agonizing Blast invocation requires you to *know* the *eldritch blast* cantrip - the All-Purpose-Tool gives you the ability to *cast* it, but that is not the same as knowing it - otherwise, for example, holding a *wand of magic missiles* would let you also cast the spell using your spell slots.

Comment: Where does it state that you must *know* the *eldritch blast* cantrip, as opposed to just being able to cast it?